# dart: stop listening to a stream after given time

Tags: timer, stream, dart, icecast

I have a Dart server, which gets meta data from icecast streams.

To get the meta data i have the following method:

```dart
void getMetaData() {

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getUrl(Uri.parse(this.src))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
        request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36");
        request.headers.add("Icy-MetaData", "1");
        return request.close();
    })
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
        if(response.headers.value("icy-metaint") != null) {
            this.offset = int.parse(response.headers.value("icy-metaint"));
            //print(response.headers.toString());
            bool stop = false;
            List<int> metaData = new List();
            streamListener = response.listen(null);
            streamListener.onData((data) {
                while(!stop) {
                    if(data.length > 17000) { stop = true; }
                }
                metaData = data.getRange(offset, offset + data[offset]*16);
                String metaDataString = new String.fromCharCodes(metaData);
                print(metaDataString);
                streamListener.cancel();
            });
            streamListener.onError((e) {
                print(e);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The method works as expected until a stream does not return any data or takes to long to return it. then it simply stops working. i assume the method does not get out of the while loop.

Thats why i probably need another condition to break the while loop. I thought a timer would be good, but i have no clue how to implement a timer to break the while lopp after 5secs or so. Or if there is a better way to obtain the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
DateTime endTime = new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(milliseconds: 5000));

while(!stop) {
  if(data.length > 17000 || new DateTime.now().compareTo(endTime) > 0) {
    stop = true;
  }
}
```

but you should better find a way to do this without this busy loop at all

Comment: Hey Günter, thanks for all your dart answers, but this one does not work. I have tried it with while(!isTimedOut) and your code right in front of the while loop. The callback of the future is never executed because of the endless while loop. The endless loop seems to block everything else, even asnyc functions.